# GUI Background color

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.9

How can I change the color of the plotting wedges to white?

and how i can make the plotting full of the screen in QT-designer?

My GUI //file:///C:/Users/Ghaliah%20Internet/Downloads/project1_sinewave.ui